# Forms-Based Authentication with SQL Azure

Tags: azure, web-config, asp.net-membership, azure-sql-database

I tried to implement the SqlMembershipProvider to connect to a database in Azure. I followed this tutorial ([Forms-Based Authentication with SQL Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh508981.aspx)). But there is a part, when it says replace the following line in your `web.config` file:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" 
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The problem that I cannot find it in my `web.config` (I use Visual Studio 2012 and started a Windows Azure Cloud Service with ASP.NET Web Role)

I did not manage to find under what tag should I put the given code line. Can someone help me out?

Comment: This is the configuration if you had your ASP.NET membership tables in a separate SQL Server **Express** file, locally, attaching that file to your SQL Server Express instance. This cannot be done in Azure like that - you'll have to put your ASP.NET membership tables into e.g. SQL Azure, and then reference that database from your config file

Comment: See [How to use ASP.NET Membership with Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2013/06/24/sample-of-jun-23rd-how-to-use-asp-net-membership-with-sql-azure.aspx) for a complete code sample on how to get this up and running